# SQL 'belong to' logic

Tags: sql, logic, belongs-to

So, I have been trying to write a query in SQL but facing an issue. I am trying to write a 'belongs to' kind of condition. What I want to do is if the values being fetched belongs to a column in another table then populate one thing otherwise populate null.
for ex.

```
NAME table
ID    NAMES
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E

XYZ table
ID
2
4
5
```

I wrote the query something like this

```
(CASE WHEN NAME.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM XYZ) THEN NAME.NAMES ELSE NULL END ) AS 'ABC'
```

This query does run but it has been running for 14 hours (OBVIOUSLY FOR A VERY HUGE AMOUNT OF DATA) and still there is no result.  Is there some flaw in this logic or is there some better way it could be done?

I expect a result like this:

```
ABC
NULL
B
NULL 
D
E
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: I always try and avoid sub query in select list. I would left join to XYZ on Name.ID and then check for a null on the key field in your case statement. At least I think so, your question is not overly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a plain left join here:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t1.NAMES END AS ABC
FROM NAME t1
LEFT JOIN XYZ t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that a `CASE` expressions else condition, if not explicitly specified, defaults to `NULL`.  This behavior works here because you want to render `NULL` if a given record in the `NAME` table does *not* match to any record in the `XYZ` table.

Comment: Thanks Tim, works like wonder.
But can you tell me what could have been the problem with my logic? I wanted to know what went wrong and why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your logic.  It is simply how the code is optimized.  The subquery is probably being run for each row in the outer query.

I would recommend switching to `exists`:

```
(case when exists (select 1 from xyz where xyz.id = name.id) then name.names
 end) as abc
```

This maintains the semantics of your original query.  In particular, there is no danger that duplicates in `xyz` would return multiple rows (as would happen with a `left join`).

For performance for this -- or for the `left join` -- you want an index on `xyz(id)`.